# when is it ok to accept an answer for a tutorial/guide question?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691008/need-tutorial-example-for-browser-extension-for-auto-payment) requiring a person to give me a tutorial/guide for a particular goal. I promptly received an answer too, but it's going to take sometime before I actually implement the given method and test the answer for myself.
So basically, unless I implement it I wouldn't know if it is right or wrong. So, *there* *is* a possibility that the answer might be incorrect too. On what basis am I supposed to judge it? Or should I just leave the answer unaccepted till I try it out for myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question was not a good fit, so it has been closed. But as for when it is it OK to accept an answer

> So basically, unless I implement it I wouldn't know if it is right or wrong. So, there *is* a possibility that the answer might be incorrect too. On what basis am I supposed to judge it? Or should I just leave the answer unaccepted till I try it out for myself.

**Yes!** Don't go accepting answers that look simply good. Don't accept the only answer you get. Don't accept the answer that the community votes up. **Accept the answer that works.**

Take as long as you need to verify it. If that's a minute, an hour, a day, even a week, take the time you need. You accepting without verifying is not doing the community or the internet a service.